# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background')

Tags: android

I got an error when I unzip my file
Error:(3, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background').

Error:(3, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background').

But in xml there is no error sign

and in my Main Activity "R." became red

```
package com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

             mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
             mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

             mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

             mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                 String title = "";


                 // Inserting navigation
                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SentFragment()).commit();
                    title = "Emergency Hotline";

                 }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit(); //firstAid (health and life)
                    title = "First Aid and Survival Tips";
                }
                // [dito ipapasok ung sa map]
                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_draft) {
                     /*FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new MapFragment()).commit(); //firstAid (health and life)*/
                     title = "Locate Hospital";

                     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                 }

               /*  if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_map) {
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new MapFragment()).commit(); //firstAid (health and life)
                     title = "Locate";
                 }*/
                 return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

                android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

                mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
}
```

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Just clean and rebuild the project (Build -> Clean project or Build -> Rebuild project).

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Assign some hex color code instead of the draw-able resource and rebuild the project